# When is MatGetArray/VecGetArray useful?

Tags: petsc

In petsc, there are already SetValues(Local) methods.  But when does one need GetArray methods?

A related question: to copy a portion of a Mat/Vec to part of another Mat/Vec, it is usually suggested that one use a Scatter object.  Is using scatter always better than the GetArray method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`MatGetArray()`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Mat/MatGetArray.html) is an advanced (should be developer) level routine that depends on the matrix format and is best avoided. It is only used with dense matrices within PETSc; there is no reason to use it otherwise. It's existence comes from users that stubbornly insist on having the function, not from meaningful use cases.

[`VecGetArray()`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Vec/VecGetArray.html), on the other hand, is the recommended way to write nonlinear residuals and other functions that need direct access to vector entries. You can use a `VecScatter` to obtain a "local" vector that contains ghost points needed during assembly, and to assemble contributions from element-partitioned subdomains (as with finite element methods). There are many examples of this in PETSc, many use [`DMDAVecGetArray()`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/DM/DMDAVecGetArray.html) to also provide convenient indexing.